# What message to use to publish the position of a rover

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I a newbie here. I've been trying to understand the appropriate message to use when publishing the position of a rover on a map. I have a topic of a "chassis" which I want to use to publish this position. I was using JointState but realised that it related to joints on the robot itself. NavSatFix is a possibility but this merely reports what the GPS says. It shouldn't be the ultimate source of truth. What I've been looking at is http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265081/what-message-to-use-to-publish-the-position-of-a-rover/) by [kenrobinson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2523/kenrobinson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if I understand the question, but if you are looking for a message type, look at the [nav_msgs/Odometry Message](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html). Its probably better if you take a look at the [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup)

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:
I think this is the answer.

@kenrobinson: 'position of a rover on a map' is typically the result of a localisation algorithm or some (derived) sensor (ie: gps, motion capture). Estimates based on sensors local to the mobile base are typically published usin the `Odom` msg that @Humpelstilzchen ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:
.. refers to. Consuming nodes typically fuse that info with other sources to improve that estimate, and the result is often used in navigation.

**Comment by [kenrobinson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2523/kenrobinson/) on 2017-06-29**:
Thank you. I'll look at the navigation stack and the Odometry message.